# why integer is added with string in System.out.println ? in java

Tags: java

```
String s = new String("5");
System.out.println(1 + 10 + s + 10 + 5);
```

output of the following function is 115105 how ?

Comment: What did you expect ?

Comment: 1105105 is the output im expecting !

Comment: @Guru "1105105 is the output im expecting" why?

Comment: So its missing the 0 from the first 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does System.out.print() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121311/how-does-system-out-print-work)

Comment: @rakeb.void that's not a dup. This is about how `+` operator works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"+" is left associative so

```
1 + 10 => 11(int)
11 + s => "115"(String)
"115" + 10 => "11510"(String) 10 is converted to String
"11510" + 5 = "115105"(String) 5 is converted to String
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code effectively functions as integer summation as long as it's possible, because the evaluation process goes from left to right. Once the String is encountered, the function switches to concatenation.

```
1 + 10 + "5" + 10 + 5
= (1 + 10) + "5" + 10 + 5
= 11 + "5" + 10 + 5
= 115105
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = new String("5");
System.out.println(1 + 10 + s + 10 + 5);
```

Since expressions are evaluated from left to rignt your code is same as

```
System.out.println((((1 + 10) + "5") + 10) + 5);
```

So first `(1 + 10)` is evaluated and since it is simple integer addition you are getting 11 so your code becomes

```
System.out.println(((11 + "5") + 10) + 5);
```

Now `(11 + "5")` is evaluated and since one of arguments is String, it is being concatenated and result will also be String. So `11` + `"5"` becomes `"11"+"5"` which gives us String `"115"`.

So after that our code is same as

```
System.out.println(("115" + 10) + 5);
```

and again in `("115" + 10)` one of arguments is String so we are getting `"115"+"10"` which gives us another String `"11510"`.

So finally we are getting to the point where we have

```
System.out.println("11510" + 5);
```

which is same as

```
System.out.println("115105");
```

Answer (score 0):

`（1 + 10）`and `10` and `5` are regarded as three strings in your code

Answer (score -1):

Java casts the integers as a string when you include a string in the addition, it becomes concatenation. Try

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class mainactivity {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        String s = new String("5");
        System.out.println((1 + 10) + s + (10 + 5));
    }    
}
```

This should output 11515.

Comment: This won't give the same result due to the parenthesis enclosing `10 + 5`.