# Java_why print member variable give actual value?

Tags: java, object, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

```
class Customer {
    public String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer c = new Customer("Sally");
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(c.name);
    }
}
```

- It's a simple question and we all know the output, but there's one quesiton about it
- Please see the code above and the Picture here [Passing Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke3D0.png)
- Question:

  1. if I print out a reference of a object like this: `System.out.println(c);`, the IDE would generate a memory address for me: `Customer@60e53b93`
  2. But, in the video tutorial(screenshot, see the image link [Passing Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke3D0.png))
     [image]

, the object have a member variable which is a **reference** to a String -> "Sally", why when I do `System.out.println(c.name)`, trying to print out a **reference**(name), it give a **real String objec**t("Sally "). **Shouldn't it print a memory address of the real Object("Sally")???**

Comment: this Customer@60e53b93 has nothing to do with memory, is just the hashcode of the object

Comment: No. Where does it say it should? A picture of a video tutorial is not sufficient ecudence for your belief, or acceptable as a part of a post here.

Comment: No, and if your Customer class had a toString() method, it would use that.

Comment: I know bro, but, what I'm trying to say is I am printing a *reference* to real object, why does it give a a String object "Sally", just like, print a *reference* of Object Customer, it would give a memory address...

Comment: @EJP sorry bro, I just want to make it clear of what actually stack and heap works, thats the reason I searched videos on YTB

Comment: @Ruizhi can you please accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: `println()` is a overloaded method in `System` class. When you call

```
    Customer c = new Customer("Sally");
    System.out.println(c);
```

This will call the `println()` method that take object as a parameter. If you refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) you will see this:

> ```
> public void println(Object x)
> ```
>
> Prints an `Object` and then terminate the line. This method calls at
>   first `String.valueOf(x)` to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.
>
> **Parameters:**
>       x - The Object to be printed.

When you call `println(c.name)`, `name` is a `String` variable, this will call the `println()` method that take `String` as the parameter:

```
System.out.println(c.name);
```

In [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()):

> **println**
>
> ```
> public void println(String x)
> ```
>
> Prints a `String` and then terminate the line. This method behaves as
>   though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.
>
> Parameters:
>        x - The String to be printed.

Also refer these: [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406703/whats-the-meaning-of-system-out-println-in-java) and [this q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121311/how-does-system-out-print-work).

Answer (score 4):

First Question Answer:- 
1.`out` is the static variable of PrintStream  in System Class.
   Which is declared in System class as

```
   public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

And when you call `System.out.println((Object)c);`
which internally call the println method of `PrintStrem` Class.
The implementation of the println mehtod in PrintStream class is as below:-

```
   public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
  public void print(Object obj) {
        write(String.valueOf(obj));
    }
```

By this code it is clear that out will call the String `ValueOf` method.
and Implemetation of ValueOf() method in String Class as below:-

```
 public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

2.String class has Override the toString method of the Object Class as Below :-

```
    /**
     * This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
     *
     * @return  the string itself.
     */
    public String toString() {
       return this;
     }
```

The `toString()` Method in Object Class:-

```
  /**
   * Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
   */
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Your class `Customer` didn't override the `toString()` method of Object class so when you Call `System.out.println(c);` it  will call the toString method of `Object` Class. Thats y you will get `Customer@60e53b93` as a output.[image]

Answer (score 2):

`System.out` is a object of class `PrintStream`. And [`PrintStream.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) calls [`String.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) for objects. And `String.ValueOf(object)` calls object.toString().
And for a String the `PrintStream.println()` prints out the string. Where as for the Customer class you are defaulting to the [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) causing to the print the Customer@ string.