# Why `toString` method is invoked when I call System.out.println for object

Tags: java, tostring

I've run into this code from geeksforgeeks. And I didn't figure out why `toString` method is invoked due to `System.out.println(c2)` . I've expected that output is `c2` object's address.

```
final class Complex {
    private  double re,  im;
    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }
    Complex(Complex c)
    {
      System.out.println("Copy constructor called");
      re = c.re;
      im = c.im;
    }            
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + re + " + " + im + "i)";
    }            
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Complex c1 = new Complex(10, 15);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(c1);    
        Complex c3 = c1;  
        System.out.println(c2);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
  Copy constructor called  
(10.0 + 15.0i)
```

Comment: Would it be more obvious if `toString` had an `@Override` annotation on it?

Comment: Whenever you override `public String toString()` this method is invoked - simple as that...

Comment: And just as importantly, any of the print methods that accept `Object` will call `toString` on said object.  The default `toString` on `Object` just prints the address of it, but any class can override `toString` to provide their own behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you call `Systme.out.println` for object type, it will try to convert the object the you passed to string by calling the following `static` method  `String.valueOf(x)` and if you look into `String.valueOf(x)` you will find the following code :

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code Object} argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an {@code Object}.
 * @return  if the argument is {@code null}, then a string equal to
 *          {@code "null"}; otherwise, the value of
 *          {@code obj.toString()} is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

if the object is not `null` called its `toString()` method

please read this [how-does-system-out-print-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121311/how-does-system-out-print-work) link for more info

Answer (score 1):

`println(Object o)` is overloaded to call `print(String.valueOf(o))` and then println()` see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)).

If the object does not override `toString()` [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is called.

You get the address from the subsequent call to hashCode(), if that method is not overridden.

Answer (score -1):

System.out.println() tends to call toString() when Object are passed. That's how it prints relatively meaningful output.