# variable out of type PrintStream in Java (not printIn problem)

Tags: java

When I run this Java code I get the error
"System.out.printLn("Java is more complicated than python");
                  ^
  symbol:   method printLn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream"
 My Code is:

```
class complicated{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.printLn("Java is more complicated than python");
    }
}
```

P.S I know this question has been asked before but I don't have System.out.printIn instead of System.out.printLn.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have System.out.printIn instead of System.out.printLn"?

Comment: You get an error because you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. It's named `println`, not `printLn`.

Comment: It is `println` not `printLn`

Comment: The real error message is *"cannot find symbol"*!  The *"location: variable out of type PrintStream"* message is telling you that the problem is with a variable called "out".

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
class complicated{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Java is more complicated than python");
    }
}
```

Here is a good link on System.out.print works:

[How does System.out.print() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121311/how-does-system-out-print-work)